# How to explode array column given a formula?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying a very basic thing in spark scala, but couldn't figure it out.

I have data like this:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| Jack | 2 |

And, I want to achieve this:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| John | 0 |
| John | 2 |
| Jack | 2 |
| Jack | 1 |
| Jack | 3 |

That is, for each row, I want to create two more rows, one is `val(col2)-1` and `val(col2)+1`.

I tried to use `explode`, but couldn't figure out how to do it properly.

```
val exploded_df = df.withColumn("col2", explode($"col2" -1, $"col2", $"col2" +1 ))
```

And, got:

> too many arguments for method explode: (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an array column to explode:

```
val exploded_df = df.withColumn("col2", explode(array($"col2" -1, $"col2", $"col2" +1 )))
```